# Does any alternative for Collect View exist in Contiki NG?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I am using Contiki-NG OS and I pretend to plot some metrics but Collect-View is removed in Contiki-NG. 
Could anyone help me with this issue?
Does any similar application exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contiki-NG there is a new application concerning power details of the motes.
A tutorial can be found in [Energest: Energy Monotoring](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Tutorial:-Energy-monitoring).

However, I don't know any application which can convert the data to a plot, like collect-view used to do. But I would also appreciate it if someone knew.